# golang http server graceful shutdown after a signal

Tags: go

I am trying to write code that gracefully shutdown the http server on signal.

My code has two go routines - `signalHandler()` and `simpleServiceStarter()` - one for signal handling and another for http server. On receiving a signal, the handler should shutdown http server 
so `simpleServiceStarter()` breaks from `ListenAndServe()`. Below is my code.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

var (
    simpleHTTPServer      http.Server
    sigChan               chan os.Signal
    simpleServiceShutdown chan bool
)

func simpleServiceStarter() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    simpleHTTPServer := &http.Server{
        Addr:           ":9000",
        Handler:        mux,
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
    }
    fmt.Printf("\nstarting http server on :9000 ")
    err := simpleHTTPServer.ListenAndServe()
    if err != http.ErrServerClosed {
        fmt.Printf("error starting simple service or closing listener - %v\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("simple service http server shutdown completed - %v\n", err)

    // communicate with main thread
    simpleServiceShutdown <- true
}

func signalHandler() {
    // Handle SIGINT and SIGHUP.
    signal.Notify(sigChan, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGHUP)

    sig := <-sigChan
    fmt.Printf("\nsignalHandler() received signal: %v\n", sig)

    // gracefully shutdown http server
    err := simpleHTTPServer.Shutdown(context.Background())
    fmt.Printf("simple service shutdown on signal %v, error: %v\n", sig, err)
    close(sigChan)

}

func main() {
    // block all async signals to this server. And we register only SIGINT and SIGHUP for now.
    signal.Ignore()

    sigChan = make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    simpleServiceShutdown = make(chan bool)
    go signalHandler()

    go simpleServiceStarter()
    <-simpleServiceShutdown // wait server to shutdown
    close(simpleServiceShutdown)
}
```

After sending the signal, the server is not breaking and still waiting.

```
Run the program as:
$ ./simpleHttp 

starting http server on :9000 
signalHandler() received signal: interrupt
simple service shutdown on signal interrupt, error: <nil>
$

From another terminal send the signal as:
tester 30202  4379  0 09:14 pts/8    00:00:00 ./simpleHttp
kill -s SIGINT 30202
```

I am using `go1.12.6 linux/amd64`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `func simpleServiceStarter()` you declare local `simpleHTTPServer := &http.Server` which shadow global

```
var (
    simpleHTTPServer      http.Server
```

this local variable can't be referenced outside of `func simpleServiceStarter()` scope. Just do `simpleHTTPServer = &http.Server` (without colon) inside `func simpleServiceStarter()`